# How to make an Evenlister container aware

Tags: symfony, doctrine

In an Eventlister I want to get to get the `security.encoder_factory`. The listener `UserManager` does know the container so `$this->get('security.encoder_factor')` obviously wont work. How should I get the `security.encoder_factory` property in this listener?

Service:

```
services:
    my.listener:
        class: Bla\OrmBundle\EventListener\UserManager
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: prePersist }
```

UserManager:

```
class UserManager  {
   public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();

        if ($entity instanceof User) {
            $factory = $this->get('security.encoder_factory');

            $encoder = $factory->getEncoder($entity);
            $password = $encoder->encodePassword($entity->getPassword(), $entity->getSalt());
            $entity->setPassword($password);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just inject container into it (but it's generally not a good practice so avoid it whenever possible):

Class:

```
class UserManager {
    protected $container;

    public function __construct(\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface $container) {
        $this->container = $container;    
    }

    protected function getEncoderFactory()
    {
        return $this->container->get('security.encoder_factory');
    }
}
```

Service definition:

```
services:
    my.listener:
        class: Bla\OrmBundle\EventListener\UserManager
        arguments: [@service_container]
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: prePersist }
```

Again, this is not a good idea! Don't make your services container aware if you don't have to! Instead you could inject encoder factory into it!!!

#### Preferred way

Class:

```
class UserManager {
    protected $encoderFactory;

    public function __construct(\Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\EncoderFactoryInterface $encoderFactory) {
        $this->encoderFactory = $encoderFactory;    
    }
}
```

Config:

```
services:
    my.listener:
        class: Bla\OrmBundle\EventListener\UserManager
        arguments: [@security.encoder_factory]
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: prePersist }
```

Comment: I implemented your second suggestion. Though it seems that the event is not fired any more.

Comment: In netbeans the `yml` validator puts an error `ScannerException while scanning for the next token we had this found character @(64) that cannot start any token